# best practices to work with images html jquery

Tags: html, image, resources

I'm making a page that shows all the posts of the users containing pictures. sometimes it is retrieved 100 post or more per navigation (like facebook).

How should I treat the images on them. They are pictures min-width:480px and long what it reach. (sometimes portrait or landscape, like facebook)

```
 POST1: Like my pic 1
   ----
  |    |
  |    |
   ----
 POST2: Like my pic 2
   ----
  |    |
  |    |
   ----
 POST3: Like my pic 3
   ----
  |    |
  |    |
   ----

    ...
```

What would be the best for optimizing the page, in order to save resources. And avoid delays, or page overload.

1) If for example I wrap a 480px-660px picture in a overflow div container of 480px-240px, It makes the image dont show completely, its just like a peview, Do I save resources by doing that? Is it a good practice?

2) I'm using a lazy-image load plugin...Do I save Resources by doing that?

3) What is the best way to show 100+ images by scroll loading, in a single page?

4) What are the best practices to load images in a single page?

Comment: See [Performance @ Google Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rail) for info on [Critical Rendering Path](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/), [decode and resize costs](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/automating-image-optimization/#reduce-unnecessary-image-decode-costs), [lazy-loading images](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/automating-image-optimization/#lazy-load-non-critical-images), etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution for your issue is to generate thumbnails for pictures with lower resolution and quality, then image size is small (optionally cuted) and page load is significantly faster.

Moreover you should partition your page and load smaller chunks e.g. 10 posts per load. This is lazy-load you mentioned. The best solution is to load more posts using offset parameter by AJAX requests (you can store in javascript variable) when user almost scrolled down to the bottom of page. When requests is finished you should append data to existing ones.

If you want to load full images you should save fullpath to image in thumbnail attribute. That's why when you upload file you should save original file and thumbnails. For example:

```
<a href="#" class="show-preview" data-img="http://example.com/img/fullimage1.jpg">
    <img src="http://example.com/img/thumbimage1.jpg"/>
</a>
```

To sum up. It's always good practice if size of data loaded by your web page are smaller. Bigger datas are only loaded when user force to it e.g. show preview etc. Even though you should convert your images for smaller sizes. If image size is 4MB and resolution is 4800x3200 in most cases is too big, so you should resize it to 1920x1080 for example.

Comment: thank you for your answer. So, what would it be the recommendation for an average thumbnail size of a picture. or the minimun in order not to lose too much resolution. In my Site's case, once the user upload a picture it trim it to a default width of 480px; but sometimes those pictures are portraits so are bigger in height. So when I retrieve them in a single page, they show up with this default sizes (480px width). Are they tooo big for being retrieved in a scroll load? I set a defaul 12 post per load in ajax, how can I improve this?

Comment: The size of thumbnail depends of how you display it in your webpage. If such image cover big part of screen the resolution should be as much big as natural size of image, for maximum width of image for the XL size screens. 

Moreover if you handle with jpg images you can change quality of image, and set it to 85/90%. This allows you to make images more smaller. The only parameter you should take care is size of image, if portrait image is 480px width and 900px height and you set worse quality you will still have small size file even though its resolution is quite high.